# Typescript error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'chai_1'

Tags: typescript, webdriver-io

Here is my demo repo https://github.com/mareru/webdriverIO-shop-demo.
I'm using webdriverIOv6 and Typescript v4.
After running `npm test`, I get this error:

```
src/pages/modules/headerModule.ts(4,7): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'chai_1'.
src/pages/modules/headerModule.ts(5,7): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'testingData_1'.
```

I tried adding `export {};` in the top of my files.
I tried adding this in `tsconfig.json` file:

```
"moduleResolution": "node",
"resolveJsonModule": true,
"esModuleInterop": true
```

But nothing helped.

This is my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"baseUrl": ".",
"paths": {
  "*": [
    "./*"
  ],
  "src/*": [
    "./src/*"
  ],
  "test/*": [
    "src/step_definitions/*"
  ]
},
/* Basic Options */
"target": "es2016",                       /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */
"module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
// "lib": [],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
// "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
// "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
// "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
// "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
// "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
// "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
// "outDir": "./",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
// "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
// "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
// "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
// "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
// "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
// "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

/* Strict Type-Checking Options */
"strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
"noImplicitAny": false,                   /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
// "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
// "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
// "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
// "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
// "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

/* Additional Checks */
// "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
// "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
// "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
// "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

/* Module Resolution Options */
"moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
// "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
// "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
// "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
// "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
"types": ["@wdio/sync","cucumber", "node", "@wdio/applitools-service"], /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
"typeRoots": ["./types"],
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,     /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
"esModuleInterop": true,                   /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
// "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */

/* Source Map Options */
// "sourceRoot": "./",                    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
// "mapRoot": "./",                       /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
// "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
// "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

/* Experimental Options */
// "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
// "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
"resolveJsonModule": true
 }
}
```

Why can't I use `import {expect} from 'chai';` in my `.ts` files?
Why can't I use  `import {testingData} from 'src/constants/testingData';` in my `.ts` files?
Where do I redeclare those variables, I just import and use them ...

Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to add your `tsconfig` to the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:
`require('ts-node').register({files: true});` in `wdio.conf.ts` in the before function was causing the troubles. I don't understand in depth why is that so, but once I have commented it out then the errors were gone.
If anybody has some in depth explanation for it, please feel free to share.
I hope this will help someone else struggling with these errors.
Thanks!

Comment: I had the same exact problem. 
"error TS2451:" which was solved by removing "require: ['ts-node/register']" from "mochaOpts" in my "wdio.conf.js"

Answer (score 0):

I had a "ton" of errors each time i started a huge legacy project. Thanks to this thread I was able to find one file with **require('ts-node').register();** in it. Commented it out and the errors are gone. So far not seeing any side effects to commenting out that line, but still a bit scared to commit it to production.